# Is there a way to hide the chart borders while converting Google Sheets into PDFs?

Tags: google-sheets, charts

The grey chart borders show up, no matter what you do in Google sheets, when converted into PDF. Is there any other way or script to make it hide while PDF conversion?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately at the date of this comment there is no way in the UI nor in Apps Script (as this just follows the UI functionallities) to achieve this. However, as this should not be intended to happen, I strongly encourage you to mention this in the [send feedback page](https://support.google.com/docs/community/?hl=en&gpf=%23!forum%2Fdocs) of google docs.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still struggling with this issue, there is a workaround where you can set the border colour to `white` instead of choosing `no border`. With this change, PDF export won't show any border lines.

Comment: you really tried this, white border really solved issue for you? This is also not working.. same already reported by many that nothing is working, except covering border by placing other same color things on all over border..

Answer (score 1):

There is a quick hack to solve this issue instead of setting the border color to full white set the border color to another white color in custom border colors.

Answer (score 0):

There's a little hack you can use, use a light color as the border color anything but white as it didn't work, you can use a very light grey color something like `#fcfcfc`. Worked for me perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Lads,

in case anyone stil struggles with this - dont save as .pdf directly but use the Print -> print to pdf function.

Hope it helps.